# Limpieza de comentarios

Tags: discusión, comentarios

La gradiente de los comentarios va desde *totalmente reveladores* a *trivialidades* que no suman nada a una pregunta y/o respuesta.

El problema actual para quien que lee los comentarios es que hay que *surfearlos* y separar los comentarios útiles de los que son puras formalidades y no aportan al contenido en si o hacen aclaraciones útiles (los que a mi me interesan)

Hay bastantes ejemplos que no voy a enumerar, a falta de tiempo.

Propongo esto:

**¿Puede cada uno eliminar sus propios comentarios que digan cosas como estas?**

- Excelente Respuesta, es lo que necesitaba!
- Gracias!
- +1 por decir que marte es rojo.
- impresionante! No sabia que 2 + 2 es 4.
- etc.. etc.. etc..

Comment: Excelente post, justo lo que es.SO necesitaba!

Comment: @Lamak a pesar de la ironía, esto no se aplica tanto a meta. ;) aquí el humor puede decir mucho mas que cien palabras.

Comment: Está disponible la opción de reportar comentarios... es inevitable que haya comentarios en las publicaciones; en lo personal, procuro que mis comentarios sean constructivos... Esta actitud ("eliminar los comentarios propios irrelevantes o triviales") es una buena cualidad; pero siempre podemos ejercer la opción de reportar los comentarios para que sean eliminados

Comment: No era con intención de ironía, sólo un poco de humor ;-), sorry

Comment: @Barranka claro, pero ya reporte 50 comentarios que siguen "pending"

Comment: @rnrneverdies No sé si los comentarios entran en la cola de revisión de "publicaciones de mala calidad" (aún no tengo acceso a ella... aquí). La gestión de reportes de publicaciones (preguntas, respuestas o comentarios) recae en los moderadores y en los usuarios que tengan acceso a las colas de revisión. En esta etapa del sitio, aún hay pocos usuarios con los privilegios requeridos, pero eso va a cambiar conforme avanza la beta. Como usuario, es necesario limitar los comentarios a cuestiones relevantes. Respecto a la revisión de reportes... creo que hay que ser un poco pacientes

Comment: @Barranka no quedan alli, los tiene que ver un moderador y no tenemos aun

Comment: @rnrneverdies Entonces... queda la paciencia. En poco tiempo habrá elección de moderadores, y entonces habrá quien pueda gestionar estos asuntos. Por ahora, para los usuarios que ya tenemos "kilometraje" en otras comunidades de StackExchange, conviene tener en cuenta tu observación

Comment: @Barranka http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26202232#26202232

Comment: @rnrneverdies Entonces hay que esperar a que JuanM elija a los moderadores

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/65

Answer (score 1):

En [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/289691) se indica que los comentarios son eliminados luego de que varios miembros los reportan o bien luego de que un moderador diamantado los elimina.

Extracto del enlace indicado arriba:

> ### Who can delete comments?
>
> A user may delete one of his own comments by clicking on the (x) icon
> that appears to the right of the comment's timestamp when the comment
> is moused over. A user can delete only one comment every five seconds.
>
> Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically.
> The number of flags needed is [based on the comment's
> score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168).  It currently takes "`3 + (Score / 3)`" flags to delete a comment.
>
> Moderators can delete any comment, or purge *all* comments from a
> post.
>
> ---
>
> ### When should comments be deleted?
>
> [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or
> answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You should
> not expect them to be around forever: Once a clarification has been
> made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the
> issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion.
> In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to
> the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they
> can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.

Comment: También en [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1625/127) se menciona que los comentarios no se deben usar para agradecimientos.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres decir es que votemos para borrar comentarios de agradecimiento ¿correcto?