# ¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?

Tags: soporte, faq, comentarios, convenciones-sociales

> Esta es una traducción de [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

Con bastante frecuencia veo usuarios que dan respuestas similares a preguntas que publico en Stack Overflow en español. Otras veces la respuesta que alguien me da es interesante, pero no útil a la hora de responder a la pregunta.

En todos los casos, tengo la necesidad de agradecer a la gente que contestó a mi pregunta. Darles un voto positivo no siempre es pertinente, mientras que una sola respuesta puede obtener la "corona" de ser aceptada. Poner un comentario diciendo "gracias" en cada respuesta me hace sentir un poco tonto.

Por tanto, ¿cuál es la etiqueta al respecto?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17886/209901).
>   Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

Para empezar, todo aquel que publique aquí con la idea de que debe ser agradecido personalmente por cada una de sus respuestas va a terminar bastante decepcionado.

Si *realmente* quieres agradecerle a alguien su buena respuesta, entonces lo que podrías hacer es dedicar un rato a mirar una de *sus* preguntas y darle una buena respuesta a una pregunta de programación que *él o ella* tenga.

Otra opción es **devolver el favor respondiendo preguntas de otros programadores**. De eso va el sitio, a fin de cuentas.

Comment: quizas yo añadiria *...darle una buena respuesta a una pregunta de programación que él o ella tenga.* si no es posible por tus conocimientos sobre esa pregunta puede plantearse la opcion de abrir un Bounty "recompensa" en favor de esa pregunta. O algo asi.Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel la idea de _pay it forward_ es que uno no devuelve el favor a la misma persona, sino a otra persona, a la comunidad. Si yo soy experto en X y me ayudan en Y, lo mejor que puedo hacer es ayudar en X al que tenga una duda, con la esperanza que el experto en Y algún día pueda beneficiarse de la ayuda de alguien experto en Z.

Comment: entiendo pero como dices o dice la traduccion -> *...entonces lo que podrías hacer es dedicar un rato a **mirar una de sus preguntas***. Yo si leo eso entiendo a las preguntas que tiene ese OP, entoces si por H o por B no tengo conocimientos para responderle, de hai lo del bounty. No dice nada en esa parte de -> *...lo mejor que puedo hacer es ayudar en X al que tenga una duda* lo pone debajo. Pero que yo entiendo ese planteamiento que dices,  pero se me ocurrio que otra forma seria la del bounty.Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel tienes toda la razón. No volví a leer esta publicación para contestarte y asumí la última parte, la de _pay it forward_. Me parece que tu sugerencia es muy buena y que lo de abrir una recompensa podría ser de gran ayuda en casos así, efectivamente. Esta es una traducción de una publicación en [meta.se], pero es wiki y yo creo que tu sugerencia la mejora, por lo que siéntete libre de editarla. ¡Gracias!

Comment: soy muy malo escribiendo, te dejaria la respuesta echa un asco a para la vista de algunos o muchos, prefirero dejarlo como comentario, pero si crees que estaria mejor dentro de la respuesta siente libre de adapatarlo si quieres y tienes tiempo. Saludos

Answer (score -9):

En si por educacion amigo, ademas el  usuario que te contesto se tomo la molestia en ayudarte sin ningun beneficio monetario, es tan solo educacion y agradecer a las persona que te ayudo.