# Jornada de Limpieza

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos, eliminación-de-preguntas

#### Intención de esta publicación

Simplemente compartir los esfuerzos realizados para limpiar y ordenar al sitio.
No se intenta generar discusión sobre prioridades o de la validez o casos que apliquen o no.
Se busca que otros usuarios puedan sumarse, y quizás sirva para coordinar esfuerzos.

---

#### Motivación

Esta es nuestra casa. Muchos de nosotros (particularmente creo que la mayoría de los que estén leyendo acá en Meta), estamos continuamente viendo cómo mejorar el sitio: preguntando, respondiendo, comentando, moderando... buscando generar el mejor contenido posible (entre muchas otras cosas que hacemos).

Fuimos observando cómo el sitio fue creciendo y mutando, viendo problemas que en algún momento existieron y otros que quizás siguen vigentes. Es un excelente momento de poner un poco de orden y limpiar algunas publicaciones. Si bien es un número alto, sigue siendo perfectamente abarcable, y tenemos que atenderlo antes de que se convierta en el monstruo que puede llegar a ser en otros sitios con más tráfico. Estoy convencido de que se puede.

La intención: **una jornada de limpieza en nuestra casa**.

---

#### No es prioritario

Antes que nada, pongamos las prioridades en orden sobre el contenido que no cumple con la calidad deseada:

1. Intentar guiar al autor de la publicación para que atienda el problema que pueda tener.
2. Reetiquetar correctamente para buscar un público más específico, mejorar el título para llamar la atención de quien pueda responder.
3. ¡Editar, editar, editar, editar! Editar todo el contenido que se pueda mejorar, agregar todo aquello que sume valor a las publicaciones.
4. Rescatar el contenido de cualquier otra forma posible.

   **...**

10. Eliminar comentarios obsoletos, no constructivos o cualquiera que no aporte a la pregunta.
11. Generar sinónimos, quemar, o editar las wikis de etiquetas con el objetivo de que las preguntas estén mejor orientadas.
12. Recién cuando no se pueda ninguna de las anteriores, cerrar o eliminar las preguntas insalvables.

Aclaro esto, porque ahora **vamos a enfocarnos en los últimos tres puntos**, pero tiene que estar claro que es un enfoque sobre publicaciones en las que fallaron todos los intentos previos.

---

#### Objetivo

**Generar y coordinar estrategias que ayuden a limpiar y ordenar al sitio.**

Se busca atacar aquellas publicaciones que quedaron rezagadas, en el olvido: ordenar y limpiar las preguntas que fueron respondidas y quedaron sin atención, así como también las preguntas que no pueden ser respondidas y son insalvables.

Entre algunas estrategias podemos nombrar: votar para cerrar, votar +1 en respuestas con 0 no aceptadas que lo merezcan, revisar el uso de etiquetas, votar -1 en preguntas de mala calidad olvidadas, comentar en el chat principal sobre buenas preguntas olvidadas que se puedan responder, votar para eliminar otras, reportar preguntas huérfanas, poner recompensas en joyas ocultas, editar y reetiquetar para que se orienten a un mejor público, responder olvidadas cuando se pueda... No sé si me olvido alguna estrategia, pero se dan una idea.

Los invito, a quienes quieran participar, a realizar un esfuerzo en una jornada de limpieza del sitio.

---

#### Chat

[toledano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/638/toledano) y yo creamos una sala de chat para conversar sobre estos temas: [Jornada de Limpieza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56002/jornada-de-limpieza)

- El chat quedó congelado, pero cualquiera puede crear un nuevo chat para seguir el tema.

---

#### Pregunta

- ¿Qué estrategia podemos utilizar para ordenar y limpiar el sitio?
- ¿A qué publicaciones estaría enfocado?
- ¿Cuál sería el resultado esperado?
- ¿Se intentó? ¿Tuvo éxito?

Comment: Esta idea es simplemente fabulosa.

Answer (score 7):

## Jornada de Limpieza (desde la sala de chat)

- Chat: [Jornada de Limpieza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56002/jornada-de-limpieza).
  Están todos invitados a entrar.

  - El chat quedó congelado, pero cualquiera puede crear un nuevo chat para seguir el tema.

#### Origen

Todo surgió de diferentes charlas en el chat principal, dispersadas en diferentes opiniones y visiones encontradas durante los últimos meses. Hace 1 mes, buscando encarar más en serio una limpieza del sitio, [toledano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/638/toledano) y yo empezamos a probar diferentes estrategias (aunque muchos otros también fueron participando). Algunas fueron más exitosas que otras, a veces mejor o peor recibidas por el resto de la comunidad, en ocasiones excediéndonos en la cantidad de preguntas que enviábamos a la cola de cierre...
- Recuerdo alguna que otra queja de [lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b), uno de los usuarios que más temprano está activo en el sitio (y que por eso se ganó el apodo ocasional de "Madrugator"), al encontrar una cola de cierre repleta.

> <sup><sup>Adenda hecha por @toledano, con permiso del OP</sup></sup>
>   Tan solo, en marzo del 2017, se hicieron 2,600 preguntas. Y al día de hoy hay casi 21,500. Esto demuestra la enorme necesidad de contar con una comunidad que comparta conocimientos y experiencia en nuestro idioma.
>
> Pero atender esta necesidad, requiere del concurso de todos. No solo para hacer preguntas, sino para **responderlas**.

---

#### Alcance

Preguntas sin actividad, olvidadas en el sitio, que actualmente están sin responder.

Principalmente para lidiar con "*la basura*". Hay muchísimas, muchísimas preguntas que son insalvables. Eso es lo que estamos abarcando en primer lugar. Hay que cerrar o eliminar muchas para poner orden, y es por donde empezamos enfocando esfuerzos en ese chat, no los puntos medios que pueden/podrían/quizás alguien podría salvar.

Las preguntas salvables están fuera del alcance de esta estrategia.

> <sup><sup>Adenda hecha por @toledano, con permiso del OP</sup></sup>
>   Al día de hoy, hay poco más de 15,500 preguntas **respondidas** o tratadas con alguna de las estrategias mencionadas por @Mariano. Han sido aceptadas, respondidas sin aceptar pero con votos positivos en una o mas respuestas o simplemente cerradas. Es ese 72% que vemos en el [*Area 51*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), un 72.09% para ser exactos.
>
> Esto significa que hay unas **6,000 preguntas sin respuesta** y aproximadamente *la mitad (**poco mas de 3 mil preguntas**) se hicieron en el 2016*.

---

#### Estrategias utilizadas

**1. Votos de cierre.** Fue el primer método que intentamos. Iniciando sobre etiquetas en las que más experiencia personal tenemos, realizamos búsquedas sobre las preguntas sin respuesta, filtrando según el caso por votos y fecha de actividad. Dentro de estos resultados encontramos una enorme cantidad de publicaciones demasiado amplias, sin que esté claro lo que se preguntaba, o con casos en los que el problema no era reproducible. Al encontrarlas, votamos a cierre para que ingresen en la cola de revisión.

- Preguntas de [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) abiertas, sin respuestas, con puntuación de 0 a 2, con menos de 25 vistas, inactivas más de 1 semana y menos de 1 mes.
  `score:0..2 answers:0 views:..25 closed:no wiki:no lastactive:1m..7d [java]`
  (y modificar los parámetros según creas conveniente)
  [Buscar en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=score%3A0..2%20answers%3A0%20views%3A..25%20closed%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20lastactive%3A1m..7d%20%5Bjava%5D)
- Preguntas de [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) abiertas, sin respuestas, con puntuación de 1 a 3, con menos de 50 vistas, inactivas más 1 mes.
  `score:1..3 answers:0 views:..50 closed:no wiki:no lastactive:..1m [java]`
  (y modificar los parámetros según creas conveniente)
  [Buscar en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=score%3A1..3%20answers%3A0%20views%3A..50%20closed%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20lastactive%3A..1m%20%5Bjava%5D)

**2. Votos +1 en respuestas que lo ameritan.** Como tarea anexa, también fuimos identificando publicaciones que tenían **(a)** buenas respuestas, **(b)** con puntaje 0 y **(c)** no aceptadas. Muchas veces algunas que fueron respondidas en momentos de poca actividad en el sitio, en otras por ser sobre un tema que aparentemente no causó mucho interés, o quién sabe por qué... En esos casos, votamos +1 a las respuestas que resolvían el problema, haciendo que pasen a ser consideradas como "respondidas".

- Preguntas no respondidas, con respuestas, con más de 1 mes inactivas
  `isanswered:no answers:1 hasaccepted:no closed:no wiki:no lastactive:..1m`
  [Buscar ahora en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=isanswered%3ano%20answers%3a1%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano%20wiki%3ano%20lastactive%3a..1m)
- SEDE: [Preguntas con respuestas no aceptadas y con puntaje <= 0](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/546331/preguntas-con-respuestas-no-aceptadas-y-con-puntaje-0)

**3. Eliminación de preguntas.** Una estrategia muy exitosa fue la de encarar reglas para eliminar preguntas insalvables. El detalle de estas estrategias, fue utilizar las reglas de roomba, filtrando aquellas preguntas abandonadas que deberían haber sido moderadas cuando fueron formuladas, pero por algún motivo escaparon a nuestros filtros.

- Búsqueda de preguntas con puntaje 0, sin respuestas, inactivas por más de 1 mes
  `answers:0 score:0 closed:no locked:no wiki:no lastactive:..1m`
  [Buscar ahora en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20score%3A0%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20lastactive%3A..1m)
- Búsqueda de preguntas de [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), con puntaje 0, sin respuestas, inactivas más de 1 mes.
  `answers:0 score:0 closed:no locked:no wiki:no lastactive:..1m [android]`
  (cambiando por la etiqueta que prefieras)
  [Buscar ahora en SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20score%3A0%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20lastactive%3A..1m%20%5Bandroid%5D)
- SEDE: [Preguntas cerca de RemoveAbandondedQuestions o RemoveDeadQuestions](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/455567/open-question-roomba?CutoffDate=2017-4-1&LastUserAccess=2018-1-1)

---

#### Resultados Esperados

Mayor porcentaje de preguntas respondidas... como consecuencia mejoran algunas estadísticas y más importante dejan de aparecer en la lista de preguntas sin respuesta, lo que permite concentrarse en preguntas que verdaderamente no han sido contestadas.<sup>[[*]](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36882501#36882501)</sup>

---

#### Resultados Obtenidos

1. En las enviadas a la cola de cierre, un gran porcentaje de preguntas fue cerrado por la comunidad (aproximadamente el 85%).
2. Buscando publicaciones con respuestas con puntaje 0, encontramos una buena cantidad de respuestas que resolvían el problema. Incluso algunas donde el autor comentaba que era la solución buscada, pero que aún así no fueron aceptadas ni votadas por nadie. Más allá del voto +1 y el comentario para el autor, resulta evidente que tenemos que votar más, a cualquier publicación útil. Creer que el voto sólo es "a un contenido asombroso" es un error, para eso existen los favoritos. Hay que votar más.
3. Se identificaron algunas preguntas abandonadas que escaparon a los filtros de moderación del sitio. Si bien hay una cantidad considerable, son menos en comparación a los puntos anteriores. No obstante, suelen ocurrir más en algunas etiquetas específicas, que creemos que tienen un menor público de expertos que estén activamente moderando.

En 1 mes, se trataron más de 300 preguntas.

> <sup><sup>Adenda hecha por @toledano, con permiso del OP</sup></sup>
>   Miren, el 19 de marzo, había 3,100 preguntas realizadas entre **octubre de 2015 y diciembre de 2016**, *sin ningún tipo de tratamiento*. Ese fue el inicio de las *Jornadas de Limpieza*. A la semana siguiente el número de preguntas *sin atender*, había disminuido a 2,922. La tendencia se ha mantenido: para el 2 de abril había 2,848. El 9 de abril, quedaban 2,814. El 16 de abril, *me dormí*. Hoy, 23 de abril, quedan 2,794.
>
> [image: Preguntas realizadas hasta dic. de 2016 sin responder]
>   <sup><sup>**Recuerden, solo hablamos de preguntas realizadas hasta el 31 de diciembre de 2016.**</sup></sup>
>
> Y es que son esas preguntas, las que están enterradas debajo de las preguntas mas nuevas, las que han recibido la atención de estas *jornadas*.
>
> Los datos presentados aquí han sido recolectados usando esta consulta, creada por @Mariano:  [Porcentaje de Preguntas Contestadas (en sitios SE o el indicador ‘% Answered’ del Area51) - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/646437/porcentaje-de-preguntas-contestadas-en-sitios-se-o-el-indicador-answered-del).
>
> Como pueden observar en esta consulta, la columna `Diferencia` se calcula restando a la columna `Preguntas` la suma de `AceptadaNoCerrada`,  `RespuestaConVotosPositivosSinAceptar_PreguntaSinCerrar`  y `Cerrada`.

### Conclusión

Para concluir, creo que todos podemos aportar un poco de nuestro tiempo atendiendo de la manera que les parezca mejor estas preguntas sin respuestas. Las herramientas están ahí. El sitio es de todos.

Comment: *Madrugator* ha venido a madrugaros a todos muahahHAHAH

Comment: ¿Es correcto cerrar una pregunta de mala calidad que no es duplicada, no está fuera de lugar, sí se entiende lo que pregunta, no es demasiado amplia y no está principalmente basada en opinión?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos como se menciona en la pregunta, "*No se intenta generar discusión sobre prioridades o de la validez o casos que apliquen o no*". Si se cierran es porque aplica uno de los motivos de cierre y 5 personas están de acuerdo.

Comment: @Mariano La pregunta está etiquetada como [discusión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discusi%c3%b3n/info).

Comment: Están todos invitados a participar del chat para ver con más detalle cualquiera de los puntos.

Answer (score 3):

## Quemar etiquetas

NOTA: Ya tenemos un hilo sobre el proceso de quemado -> [¿Cuál es el proceso de remover etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)

### Origen

El "quemado" de etiquetas es una vieja práctica en la red de sitios Stack Exchange. En el sentido original, consiste en de retirar una mala etiqueta de todas las preguntas que la tienen. En el sentido dado en [Quemar etiqueta [errores]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1060/65), además los desarrolladores de SOes colocan la etiqueta en la lista negra de tal forma que no se puede usar "nunca más".

### Estrategias utilizadas

- Proceso normal de edición de preguntas

  - ¿Quién? Todos.
- Discutir en meta acerca de una etiqueta dudosa.

  - ¿Quién? Todos.
  - Ejemplo: [¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65)
- Crear solicitudes de quemado

  - ¿Quién? Todos.
  - Ejemplos derivados del ejemplo previo

    - [Quemar etiqueta [studio]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1740/65)
    - [Quemar etiqueta [visual]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1732/65)
- Poner etiqueta en la lista negra

  - ¿Quién? Desarrolladores de SOes

### Resultados Esperados

Pendiente

### Resultados Obtenidos

Por determinarse

### Conclusión

Por determinarse

## Ejemplos Abril 2017

[Búsqueda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsolicitud-de-quemado%5D+created%3A2017-04-01..2017-04-30+is%3Aquestion)

- [Quemar etiqueta [error]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1738/65)

Answer (score 3):

## Eliminar comentarios

#### Estrategias utilizadas

Dejo mi metodología para reportar comentarios.

Primero voy a la lista de preguntas, en mi caso, los busco intencionalmente.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=votes

Yo recomendaría mirar las preguntas que tienen entre 15 y 10 votos, ya que los comentarios en respuestas con puntaje superior a eso, ya los reporté.

---

#### Resultados obtenidos

Por determinarse.

---

#### Conclusión

Por determinarse.

---

#### Ejemplos

Ejemplo de comentario reportable:

> @Oriol es cierto, lo escribí de memoria. cuando tenga algo de tiempo voy a editar el post e incluir la información actualizada. gracias por el mencionarlo [Emanuel Ve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/emanuel-ve) el [16 dic. 15 a las 23:33](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450/c%C3%B3mo-diferenciar-entre-un-objeto-y-un-arreglo-en-javascript#comment1931_454)

¿Por qué reportar este tipo de comentarios? En este caso, sugiero reportarlo como "obsoleto".

Lo más probable es que @Oriol ya haya visto el comentario, y solo dice que va a editar la publicación. No agrega ninguna información, solo sirve como aviso transitorio.

Otro ejemplo: Yo lo reportaría como "muy conversador".

> @devconcept me preocupa el comentario de georg en esa pregunta. No estoy muy seguro a que se refiere – [Carlos Muñoz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/20/carlos-mu%C3%B1oz) el [16 mar. 16 a las 18:09](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450/c%C3%B3mo-diferenciar-entre-un-objeto-y-un-arreglo-en-javascript#comment10651_453)

Comment: Otra opción es buscar comentarios que tengan palabras claves como "+1", "gracias", etc. Se puede usar este query en SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/476438/search-comments-or-view-top-comments

Answer (score 2):

## Traducción de etiquetas

> He creado esta respuesta inicialmente para ser publicada como respuesta a [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/65) pero me parece que este es el lugar más apropiado.

### Cómo se traduce una etiqueta

#### Resumen

En el caso de las etiquetas, úsese la característica de sinónimos.

#### Explicación

Punto y aparte de lo que los desarrolladores de este sitio y los moderadores diamantados pueden hacer, los miembros que cumplen ciertas condiciones pueden participar en lograr que el sitio tenga más elementos en español. En el caso particular de las etiquetas, lo primero es crear una etiqueta en español para ser usada como etiqueta maestra y luego hacer la etiqueta en inglés sinónimo de aquella.

> Nota: No en todos los casos debe tenerse una etiqueta en español. En caso de duda o discrepancias, se puede discutir [en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56002/jornada-de-limpieza) o publicar una pregunta en Meta.
>
> - El chat quedó congelado, pero cualquiera puede crear un nuevo chat para seguir el tema.

#### Quienes pueden participar

1. Se requiere una reputación igual o mayor a 1,250 para tener el privilegio de crear sinónimos
2. Se requiere de una puntuación mayor o igual a 5 en respuesta a preguntas con la etiqueta maestra para poder proponer o votar un sinónimo.
3. La puntuación de cada usuario se muestra en la página sobre etiquetas en el perfil de usuario del usuario en cuestión.

   `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/<pon-aquí-tu-id>?tab=tags`
4. Los sinónimos se proponen y votan en la página de sinónimos de la etiqueta. Estas páginas tienen un URL como el siguiente:

   `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/<pon-aquí-la-etiqueta-maestra>/synonyms`
5. Se requieren 4 votos positivos para hacer que un sinónimo se active. Con dos votos negativos la propuesta de sinónimo se elimina.

#### Caso especial: Etiquetas predeterminadas en Meta

En Meta, existen **etiquetas predeterminadas** en inglés las cuales existen aún y cuando no haya una pregunta que las use, sin embargo, para poder crear un sinónimo, debe existir al menos una pregunta con que use tanto la etiqueta maestra como la etiqueta a declarar como sinónimo.

A continuación se listan las **etiquetas predeterminadas en Meta** y la etiqueta en español sugerida como maestra, tomando como base la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1888/65) creada por fedorqui a [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/65). Abajo en cada etiqueta se indica el enlace a la página de sinónimos correspondiente a la etiqueta sugerida como maestra, y en caso de existir una pregunta sobre la definición de sinónimo, se pone el enlace correspondiente.

> Pase el puntero sobre la etiqueta para ver el resumen de la etiqueta. Si la etiqueta no tienen ninguna pregunta, quienes cuentan con permiso de edición **pueden agregar la etiqueta** a una pregunta existente. Quienes tienen los privilegios para crear nuevas etiquetas, además podrían **crear una pregunta con la etiqueta** en cuestión.

**Algunas de las etiquetas maestas con mayor número de respuestas**

- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) → [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/etiquetas/synonyms
- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) → [sinonimos-de-etiquetas](/questions/tagged/sinonimos-de-etiquetas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sinonimos-de-etiquetas/synonyms
- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) → [votos](/questions/tagged/votos)

  - [Hagamos [votes] sinónimo de [votos]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1889/65)

    - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/votos/synonyms
- [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) → [reputación](/questions/tagged/reputaci%c3%b3n)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/reputación/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/reputaci%C3%B3n/synonyms)
- [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) → [comentarios](/questions/tagged/comentarios)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/comentarios/synonyms
- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) → [medallas](/questions/tagged/medallas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/medallas/synonyms
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) → [motivos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/motivos-de-cierre)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/motivos-de-cierre/synonyms
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) → [moderación](/questions/tagged/moderaci%c3%b3n)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderación/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderaci%C3%B3n/synonyms)
- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) → [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones)

  - [Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1743/127)

    - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/ediciones/synonyms
- [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) → [recompensas](/questions/tagged/recompensas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/recompensas/synonyms
- [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer) → [respuesta-aceptada](/questions/tagged/respuesta-aceptada)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/respuesta-aceptada/synonyms
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) → [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/data-explorer/synonyms

**Otras**

- [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) → [preguntas](/questions/tagged/preguntas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/preguntas/synonyms
- [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) → [respuestas](/questions/tagged/respuestas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/respuestas/synonyms
- [search](/questions/tagged/search) → [búsqueda](/questions/tagged/b%c3%basqueda)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/búsquead/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/b%C3%BAsquead/synonyms)
- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) → [votar](/questions/tagged/votar)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/votar/etiquetas/synonyms
- [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) → [interfaz-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/interfaz-de-usuario)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/interfaz-de-usuario/synonyms
- [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) → [pregunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pregunta-espec%c3%adfica)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/pregunta-específica/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/pregunta-espec%C3%ADfica/synonyms)
- [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) → [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) =

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/markdown/synonyms
- [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) → [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad)

  - [Sinónimo [wiki-de-comunidad] ← [community-wiki] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1774/127)

    - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/wiki-de-comunidad/synonyms
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) → [votos-negativos](/questions/tagged/votos-negativos)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/votos-negativos/synonyms
- [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) → [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) =

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/openid/synonyms
- [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) → [migración](/questions/tagged/migraci%c3%b3n)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/migración/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/migraci%C3%B3n/synonyms)
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) → [voto-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/voto-de-cierre)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/voto-de-cierre/synonyms
- [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) → [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos)

  - [Sinónimo [duplicados-exactos] ← [exact-duplicates] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1778/83)

    - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/duplicados-exactos/synonyms
- [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) → [código-de-conducta](/questions/tagged/c%c3%b3digo-de-conducta)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/etiqueta/synonyms
- [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications) → [notificaciones](/questions/tagged/notificaciones)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/notificaciones/synonyms
- [users](/questions/tagged/users) → [usuarios](/questions/tagged/usuarios)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/usuarios/synonyms
- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) → [preguntas-cerradas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-cerradas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/preguntas-cerradas/synonyms
- [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks) → [hipervínculos](/questions/tagged/hiperv%c3%adnculos)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/hypervínculos/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/hyperv%C3%ADnculos/synonyms)
- [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump) → [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/data-dump/synonyms
- [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) → [formular-preguntas](/questions/tagged/formular-preguntas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/formular-preguntas/synonyms
- [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) → [eliminar](/questions/tagged/eliminar)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/eliminar/synonyms
- [recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity) → [actividad-reciente](/questions/tagged/actividad-reciente)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/actividad-reciente/synonyms
- [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) → [nuevos-usuarios](/questions/tagged/nuevos-usuarios)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/nuevos-usuarios/synonyms
- [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) → [reportar](/questions/tagged/reportar)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/reportar/synonyms
- [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) → [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) =

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/chat/synonyms
- [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions) → [preguntas-sin-respuestas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-sin-respuestas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/preguntas-sin-respuestas/synonyms
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) → [reetiquetar](/questions/tagged/reetiquetar)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/reetiquetar/synonyms
- [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) → [cuentas-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/cuentas-de-usuario)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cuentas-de-usuario/synonyms
- [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) → [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)

  - [Sinónimos de [formato] en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1769/83)
- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) → [etiquetas-interesantes](/questions/tagged/etiquetas-interesantes)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/formato/synonyms
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) → [votos-positivos](/questions/tagged/votos-positivos)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/votos-positivos/synonyms
- [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) → [estadísticas](/questions/tagged/estad%c3%adsticas)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/estadísticas/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/estad%C3%ADsticas/synonyms)
- [login](/questions/tagged/login)  → [inicio-de-sesión](/questions/tagged/inicio-de-sesi%c3%b3n)

  - [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/inicio-de-sesión/synonyms](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/inicio-de-sesi%C3%B3n/synonyms)
- [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) → [favoritos](/questions/tagged/favoritos)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/favorites/synonyms
- [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) → [preguntas-eliminadas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-eliminadas)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/preguntas-eliminadas/synonyms
- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) → [etiquetar](/questions/tagged/etiquetar)

  - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/etiquetar/synonyms

**No se requiere traducir**

- [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange)
- [rss](/questions/tagged/rss)
- [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)

## Preguntas relacionadas

- [¿Por qué es necesario tener 5 votos positivos en una etiqueta para poder proponer un sinónimo de etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/850/65)
- [¿Cómo se crean los sinónimos de etiquetas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1192/65)

## Artículos de ayuda relacionados

- [Privilegio: Crear sinónimos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)