# ¿La calidad de una respuesta depende de la calidad de una pregunta?

Tags: discusión

en concreto pregunto esto debido a lo que me pasó con la pregunta [Como hacer un array multidimensional?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117037/como-hacer-un-array-multidimensional/117039?noredirect=1#comment217135_117039)

Recibí votos negativos al parecer porque la pregunta solo preguntaba acerca de un concepto, y no planteaba una necesidad en específico y porque no esperé a que el usuario mejorara la calidad de su pregunta al grado subjetivo que otros esperaban.

Decidí en vista de ello hacer una respuesta muy completa con la intención de que se volviera un wiki de comunidad, pues una pregunta aparentemente simple como esta puede hacer que muchos aprendamos, incluso aquellos que ya llevamos más de una década programando.

Por ello quisiera saber si la política de esta versión en castellano será tener preguntas complejas en contraposición con tener información útil. Si nos debemos de centrar en el conocimiento o en resolver problemas.

Comment: No necesita ser compleja la pregunta, solo se espera cierto esfuerzo por parte del autor. Las preguntas hechas "a la primera de cambio" sin haberlo intentado no deberían responderse. Si el autor ha intentado algo pero se le olvidó añadirlo, siempre puede editar la pregunta para mejorarla, entonces veríamos qué problema exacto tiene y con ellos podríamos explicarle como solucionarlo. Por como esta formulada la pregunta, no parece haber recurrido siquiera a la documentación, que está disponible en español. Un saludo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hay ciertos aspectos en que la calidad de una respuesta depende de la pregunta. Imagina, por ejemplo, que escribes una excelente respuesta sobre como solucionar los interbloqueos. Sin duda se merecería muchos positivos. Pero si el autor ha preguntado como utilizar un tipo covariante en Scala para definir una relación entre clases entonces tu respuesta no es buena, está fuera de tema.

No es el caso de la respuesta que planteas. La cual sí es apropiada para la pregunta que te han hecho. ¿Por qué los negativos? Tiene que ver con lo que se explica en inglés [aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/956880) y de lo cual extraigo y traduzco la parte relevante a lo que nos ocupa a continuación:

En Stack Overflow hay varios tipos de usuarios:

- Los cuidadores que quieren mantener el sitio limpio y con buen contenido. Serían quienes por ejemplo participan en [Jornada de Limpieza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/jornada-de-limpieza)
- Los vampiros "damelo todo hecho" que inundan el sitio con preguntas malas y duplicadas que solo quieren que les solucionen su problema y no les importa el sitio.
- Los obsesionados con ganar reputación que responderán cualquier cosa que puedan, o incluso que no puedan.
- Apáticos, a los que ya les da todo igual
- Los que hacen buenas preguntas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La persona que ha preguntado puede que sea o no sea un vampiro. Puede que esté acostumbrado a otros sitios y no comprenda como funciona este. Puede haber muchos motivos. Se nota en el hecho de que ponga que "acaba de iniciar sus estudios" que es algo completamente fuera del estilo de este sitio. Aquí procuramos centrarnos en el detalle técnico.

¿Y las personas que te han votado negativo? Probablemente son cuidadores. Les preocupa tanto que el sitio se ajuste a su modelo idealizado que no solo votan negativo a la pregunta (lo cual está justificado) sino que además votan negativo a las respuestas pues entienden que si a un vampiro le das una respuesta este volverá a hacer más y más preguntas malas. Es decir, entienden que quien responde una pregunta mala está indirectamente contribuyendo a empeorar el sitio. Por eso el negativo.

¿Es correcto actuar así? Es discutible.

Comment: OMFG si sigo en este sitio me volveré un hater! creo que me quedé en el summer of love permanentemente. Me gustaría que propusieras algo además de tu valiosa opinión para que los colegas tengan una propuesta de como actuar.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro ¿Y qué voy a proponer? Propongo que si una pregunta es mala se vote negativo a la pregunta. Y si recibe una respuesta buena no votes negativo a la respuesta. Propongo coherencia; si crees que solo las preguntas buenas deben ser respondidas o crees que hay que esperar 24h ante una pregunta que no es buena y ves una pregunta en meta que no te parece suficientemente buena como para que le votes positivo entonces no respondas (obsérvese que en el momento de escribir este comentario yo soy el único que votó positivo la pregunta de Ruslan).

Comment: Yo les propongo otra cosa.. edita la pregunta, para que quede bien.. o has tu propia pregunta, correcta y completa, y pon tu respuesta ahi. De esa forma tienes las dos cosas que buscabas, buenas pregutnas y buenas respuestas.. @RuslanLópezCarro (creo que soy del tipo 1 ajaja)

Comment: @gbianchi Excelente sugerencia. De hecho lo que tu sugieres es lo ideal y es lo que debiera hacer quien tenga tiempo, ganas y conocimiento. A quien carezca de una de esas cosas (que somos todos en alguna ocasión) es a quien dirijo mi propuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Este es un tema que ya se ha discutido anteriormente, y considero que varios de los puntos vienen descritos en el centro de ayuda.

En la página [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) menciona justo al inicio **Busca, e investiga**. Esto tiene un objetivo y básicamente se refiere a que las preguntas del tipo "Hazme la tarea escolar", "Busca por mí y explícame el concepto", (o algunos otros que vienen descritos a detalle en la publicación [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo)), son tan amplios que esto se convertiría en un foro, se convertiría en el sitio del "hazlo por mí", cada quien entendería lo que quisiera y el verdadero objetivo es resolver preguntas puntuales de problemas de programación.

Stack Overflow en español no tiene (ni debe) que pasar por la misma curva de aprendizaje que pasó la versión en inglés, estamos tomando las mejores prácticas de la versión en inglés la cual ya tiene 9 años de haber sido lanzada y con esto estamos construyendo un sitio sólido, con unas bases fuertes en cuanto al uso y moderación del sitio.

Los usuarios que sí leen el centro de ayuda podrán notar que existen reglas, recomendaciones y una página dedicada a cada tópico referente al uso del sitio, sin importar si son para preguntas o para respuestas, medallas, reputación, etc.

Mi recomendación es la siguiente. No veas esto como la versión en inglés, usan la misma plataforma tecnológica pero culturalmente no tienen porque ser igual. ¿Puedes responder preguntas de este tipo? Claro, aunque la comunidad puede estar o no de acuerdo contigo. Paciencia a la hora de responder ya que la subjetividad trae consigo especulaciones y la publicación puede quedar peor de como empezó. Y sobre todo, ante cualquier duda, siempre puedes acudir al centro de ayuda o al chat.

Comment: El motivo por el que han votado negativo a Ruslan no aparece en [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo). Ni su respuesta "es solamente código." ni "solamente pusiste un link." ni "es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.". Le han votado negativo por responder a una mala pregunta que sí esta dentro del tema del sitio.

Comment: Exactamente, una táctica que teníamos al inicio para evitar convertir el sitio en uno de cazarrecompensas era volver las preguntas que eran petición de información (y no una solicitud de ayuda) una wiki de comunidad para no dar puntos a nadie y yo esperaba que ese fuera el caso con esta. La idea detrás de las wikis de comunidad es atraer gente que viene usando los buscadores para ayudarse, mostrando de paso que en este sitio hay expertos y qeu no es solamente un grupo de amigos en línea. De cualquier amnera gracias, no había leido con detenimiento eso de "contesta preguntas bien hechas".

Answer (score 3):

Todos los seres humanos tenemos una forma de pensar y actuar diferente, podríamos vivir sin leyes, en este caso realizar preguntas y respuestas en base al [libre albedrío](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libre_albedr%C3%ADo), pero definitivamente sabemos que esto sería un caos!.

**Si eres usuario del sitio es importante revisar lo que esta definido en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), si hablamos de realizar una pregunta hay que realizarla en base a lo definido en [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) en cuanto a respuestas revisa el documento [Respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).**

Lo que busca el sitio es tener una base de datos de usuario donde todos los niveles desde noveles hasta expertos, donde exista información de calidad y un lugar donde podamos preguntar y responder con toda confianza, y lo más importante que esta información perdure y sea de utilidad a nuevos usuarios.

Ya lo comento nuestro Community Manager, SO en español es un poco diferente, una de las características es que somos un poco más pacientes y tratamos de ayudar evitando ser [tiranos o hacer bullying a nuevos usuarios](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-so-many-bullies-on-Stack-Overflow), **es muy importante la ayuda de la comunidad**, dirigir a nuevos usuarios por buen camino. Para un moderador es fácil realizar el cierre de preguntas mal formuladas, pero tratamos primeramente de indicar al usuario novel la forma correcta de como debe convivir en el sitio.

Realizas una comparación sobre las preguntas que se realizan en SO en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431670/how-to-define-single-and-multidimensional-array-in-php

este tipo de preguntas en realidad buscan un tutorial, incluso el usuario no acepto ninguna respuesta, de hecho tampoco ha realizado el [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio.

Debido a la gran cantidad de preguntas/respuestas realizadas en SO en inglés en ocasiones encuentro que este tipo de publicaciones permanecen en el sitio,  algunas que son únicamente comentarios y no son marcados por los usuarios para que los moderadores actúen.

**Es indispensable la ayuda de la comunidad para ayudar y guiar a los nuevos usuarios.**

---

En cuanto a las [**respuestas**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), esto es un extracto de lo que lo que indica el centro de ayuda:

> Contesta preguntas bien formadas
>
> **No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que…**
>
> - ... son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real.
> - ...solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades.
> - ...ya se han preguntado antes y se han contestado varias veces.
> - ...requieren demasiada dirección para que puedas contestarla completamente.
> - ...no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo como lo definimos en el Centro de ayuda.
>
> No se te olvide que puedes editar la pregunta que estas contestando
>   para mejorar la claridad y el enfoque.

Si bien es cierto realizaste una respuesta lo cual es de agradecer, pero la pregunta sin duda es de baja calidad, **solo hay que votar en contra si el contenido de la pregunta/respuesta es de baja calidad**.

Sin embargo si continuas realizando esto, **en realidad estas fomentando a que nuevos usuarios realicen preguntas de baja calidad, lo cual es algo que deseamos evitar.**

Comment: Gracias, pero te centras sobre todo en las preguntas, y por lo que fui penalizado fue por una respuesta, y como verás en la liga que pusiste, las respuestas no están penalizadas a pesar ded que el sitio en inglés tiene fama de ser más estricto y puritano. Obviamente revisé el centro de ayuda y el como esponder. Agradecería una propuesta y no solo una opinión, pues si pregunté es en busca de una política de comportamiento que todos compartieramos en la comunidad. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias Ruslan, actualicé mi respuesta en relación a lo comentado.

Answer (score 3):

Ya has recibido varias respuestas muy buenas, pero no me resisto a ofrecer mi visión del tema.

El problema, como ya se ha dicho, no es la calidad de la pregunta. El problema es que la pregunta demuestra una falta total de investigación previa, algo que está especificado en el centro de ayuda claramente. En el caso que planteas, una búsqueda de 5 segundos en Google habría dado al OP infinidad de respuestas a su pregunta.

Yo no suelo votar negativo a respuestas realizadas a preguntas con una manifiesta falta de investigación, pero si es cierto que soy totalmente contrario a ellas ya que alientan a los nuevos usuarios a usar el sitio como su buscador personal. Esto además no les ayuda, ya que si insisten con este tipo de preguntas pueden [acabar baneados para preguntar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2911/15301).

En mi opinión en estos casos es muy importante ser pedagógicos con este tipo de usuarios. Añadir un comentario explicando claramente como mejorar su pregunta y cuales son las normas del sitio para que puedan mejorar su pregunta o al menos tratar de hacerlo en futuras nuevas preguntas.

Otra cuestión que quiero dejar clara cuando se ponen ejemplos de Stack Overflow en Inglés, algo que se suele hacer de vez en cuando por aqui. Es muy importante fijarse en la fecha de la pregunta, ya que en los orígenes del sitio las normas no se encontraban claramente establecidas. @Jorgesys pone el siguiente ejemplo:

[how to define single and multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431670/how-to-define-single-and-multidimensional-array-in-php)

y tu comentas lo siguiente:

> como verás en la liga que pusiste, las respuestas no están penalizadas a pesar de que el sitio en inglés tiene fama de ser más estricto y puritano

La cuestión es que la pregunta es de Marzo de 2011, con lo que no es ejemplo del funcionamiento actual. Yo te invito a que vayas al sitio en inglés y contestes hoy en día una pregunta tan falta de investigación previa como la que nos ocupa. Si no me equivoco, recibirías un gran numero de votaciones negativas igual que aquí.

En tu pregunta añades:

> Decidí en vista de ello hacer una respuesta muy completa con la intención de que se volviera un wiki de comunidad, pues una pregunta aparentemente simple como esta puede hacer que muchos aprendamos, incluso aquellos que ya llevamos más de una década programando.

Y yo te lo agradezco de verdad, todo lo que pueda enriquecer el sitio es interesante. Yo mismo he creado alguna respuesta "canónica" para temas que puede ser interesante que formen parte de la base de conocimiento del sitio. Pero en mi opinión lo que deberías hacer es crear tu mismo una pregunta y posteriormente autoresponderte. De esa manera, la información es añadida al sitio sin el efecto negativo de alentar que los nuevos usuarios realicen preguntas de baja calidad.

Por último, que ya me estoy extendiendo demasiado, debemos tener en cuenta que aquí somos muchos usuarios, y cada uno tiene tiene su visión (no se si idealizada o no Jose Antonio Dura Olmos ;)) de lo que debe ser el sitio. Lo importante es que todos estamos aquí para lo mismo, que es tratar de ayudarnos unos a otros. Por supuesto vamos a tener discrepancias, y para eso está Meta, para tratar todos los temas en los que pueda haber diferencias de opinión e intentar llegar a acuerdos. Pero de todas maneras, al final, el sistema de votaciones es individual, secreto, y a criterio de cada uno. No tiene mucho sentido tratarlo aquí ya que cada uno vota lo que le parece, y es importante entender que los votos negativos (o los positivos) no son a la persona, sino al post en concreto. Tomárselo como algo personal es no entender el funcionamiento de un sistema como es el de StackExchange.

Te animo a que sigas aportando al sitio, entre todos haremos Stack Overflow en Español el sitio de referencia para los programadores que hablamos Español :)

Comment: Pido humildemente perdón por el ladrillo que os he soltado. Lo siento mucho, no volverá a ocurrir :)

Comment: Nada que disculpar, tus respuestas son extremadamente buenas.

Comment: La falta de investigación que mencionas es relevante. Que "una búsqueda de 5 segundos en Google habría dado al OP infinidad de respuestas a su pregunta." es irrelevante. Siendo todo lo demás igual, una pregunta que se pude responder con una búsqueda de 5 segundos es tan válida como una que requiere 5 horas. Y es irrelevante entre otras cosas porque esa infinidad de respuestas está llena de respuestas incorrectas, obsoletas e incluso peligrosas. ¿Y cómo diferenciar las buenas? Precisamente quien mejor puede diferenciarlas es quien no necesita preguntar. Por eso este sitio.

Comment: Por eso no debemos dificultar las preguntas que se pueden solventar con una búsqueda de 5 segundos. Porque aquí las respuestas no se presentan cronológicamente (salvo que quieras) o desordenadamente. Se presentan ordenadas por mérito (más o menos, hay una cierta relación difusa entre votos y mérito). Y esto es mucho más útil que una infinidad de respuestas en 5 segundos. Lo cual no quita que la pregunta fuese mala, pero quería aclarar este punto. Nunca debieramos usar "se resuelve con búsqueda de 5 segundos" como argumento salvo que sea una búsqueda en SO, es decir, un duplicado.

Comment: Yo no diría que es irrelevante, ya que es la demostración clara de que no existe un trabajo de investigación previa a la pregunta, algo que es lo mínimamente exigible en el sitio. Otra cosa es que, tras esa investigación, el usuario que pregunta aclare que no ha entendido lo que ha encontrado o que tiene dificultades. Yo sigo defendiendo que debemos hacer entender a los usuarios nuevos que la investigación previa es el mínimo exigible para recibir una respuesta, y de eso va todo este tema.Por eso no creo que la "busqueda de 5 segundos" sea irrelevante, ahi no podemos estar de acuerdo :)