# ¿De qué manera puedo contribuir positivamente al sitio?

Tags: soporte, bloqueo-de-publicación

El problema es que ya no puedo formular preguntas debido a que se me ha ha prohibido el privilegio... Y en el centro de ayuda me dice que para que me quiten el baneo debo contribuir positivamente al sitio... ¿Cuales son las maneras de contribuir positivamente?

---

El artículo referido es [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Parece un buen momento para traducir [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/209901).

Comment: En este caso sería más adecuado : [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta? ¿Cómo puedo salir de la prohibición de preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Retiré la etiqueta [meta-tag:centro-de-ayuda] ya que la pregunta hace referencia a un artículo de ayuda en específico, no al centro de ayuda en general pero no se refiere a un problema o característica del centro de ayuda o del artículo en sí, sino a las reglas de participación en el sitio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En SO hay un sistema automático para bloquear usuarios. El algoritmo es secreto para evitar que haya quien juegue a "vivir justo en el filo del peligro".

Pero sí sabemos algo que puedes hacer para solventar la situación. Arreglar las preguntas y respuestas que ya has hecho. No puedes hacer nuevas pero sí puedes editar las antiguas.

Nadie, salvo algunos empleados y/o dueños de Stack Overflow, sabe exáctamente como es, pero cabe imaginar que si editas tus preguntas y respuestas lo suficiente como para recibir suficientes votos positivos tu bloqueo será automáticamente retirado.

Las hay en que podrás mejorar como:

[¿Cómo hacer una copia de seguridad en Base De Datos SQL Server desde Visual Basic?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32825/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-una-copia-de-seguridad-en-base-de-datos-sql-server-desde-visual-basi)

[Cómo usar PWDENCRYPT y PWDCOMPARE con SQL Sever?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/c%C3%B3mo-usar-pwdencrypt-y-pwdcompare-con-sql-sever)

[¿Cómo obtener el tiempo transcurrido desde que se guardó un registro en una base de Datos desde Visual Basic?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/c%C3%B3mo-usar-pwdencrypt-y-pwdcompare-con-sql-sever)

Las tres son preguntas muy cortas, tres líneas como mucho. Sin detalles. Sin código. Eso en general no está muy bien visto en esta comunidad. Aunque curiosamente todas han recibido respuestas. No puede uno menos que pensar: "Si alguien se ha tomado la molestia de responder será que la pregunta no era tan mala". Pero la comunidad es como es, si quieres que te acepten, **detalles**, **ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable**, **demostrar esfuerzo** y **labor de investigación**.

Dado que has publicado en meta es muy posible que muchas personas revisen tus preguntas y recibas votos positivos si te tomas la molestia de mejorarlas. Aprovecha el "efecto meta".

Más complicado es el tema de preguntas como:

[¿Por qué no me funciona consulta con Ajax en ASP.NET? [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32825/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-una-copia-de-seguridad-en-base-de-datos-sql-server-desde-visual-basi)

> Las preguntas que necesitan trabajo adicional o que no encajan en este
>   sitio pueden ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la
>   comunidad. Mientras las preguntas estén en espera, no pueden ser
>   respondidas, pero pueden ser editadas para hacerlas elegibles para
>   reapertura.

Pero entre quienes la han cerrado tienes a quien la ha respondido. Esto no tiene ningún sentido. Si piensas que la pregunta no encaja en el sitio entonces cualquier respuesta igualmente no va a encajar. Si la pregunta necesita trabajo adicional entonces una respuesta debiera esperar a ese trabajo adicional. Votar para cerrar a la vez que se responde no es lógico. Me temo que en estos casos el problema no eres tu y no puedes hacer nada para remediarlo. Concéntrate en las otras.

Y para acabar un consejo. Vota positivo en todas las respuestas que aceptes. Tienes respuestas que has aceptado con 0 votos.

Answer (score 4):

Como bien se comenta las acciones de tu usuario que se pueden activar son :

> - bloqueado para formular preguntas.
> - bloqueado para responder.
> - limitado a 1 pregunta por semana.
> - bloqueado para sugerir ediciones.
> - bloqueado para realizar revisiones.

Es un algoritmo el que activa estas acciones, aún los moderadores no pueden activar estas acciones.

Revisando tu perfil, efectivamente estas bloqueado para formular preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedes solucionar esta situación?, revisa:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

¿Cómo puedo salir de la prohibición de preguntar?

> **La prohibición será levantada automáticamente por el sistema cuando
> determine que tus contribuciones positivas superen aquellas preguntas
> que fueron percibidas negativamente.**
>
> La única manera de acabar con la prohibición es contribuir
> positivamente al sitio, las prohibiciones automáticas nunca expiran o
> vencen. **Comienza por arreglar tus preguntas existentes**, no publiques
> la misma pregunta nuevamente. Se espera que todas las preguntas sean
> útiles también para visitantes futuros, así que esfuérzate en escribir
> con gramática y ortografía apropiadas, con formato agradable a la
> vista e incluyendo todo el detall posible sobre tu problema y que has
> intentado previamente. Leer tu pregunta en voz alta para tí mismo
> puede ayudarte a entender como le sonará a otros. Aquí tienes algunas
> recomendaciones adicionales para escribir preguntas buenas y útiles: