# ¿Por qué ya no puedo publicar respuestas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, bloqueo-de-publicación

El sistema me ha bloqueado y ya no me deja publicar respuestas. ¿Por qué me pasó? ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Te invito a leer [¿Porqué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: También puedes leer esta respuesta:  [Contribuciones positivas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2911/de-qué-manera-puedo-contribuir-positivamente-al-sitio/2914?r=SearchResults#2914)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El sistema te ha bloqueado de responder. Ha sido automático.

También puede bloquearte de preguntar, pero no es tu caso.

Mirando tu perfil, veo que tienes 4 respuestas:

- una ha sido borrada por ser un comentario en la sección de respuestas.
- otra la eliminaste tú mismo pero también fue votada negativamente por ser un comentario.
- Otra la eliminaste, pese a que no era un comentario, porque la respuesta era incorrecta.
- Y la última sigue publicada (aunque no debería responderse preguntas cuyo problema es un fallo tipográfico. Se debe reportar como tal).

En el enlace [¿Porqué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) indican que has de arreglarlas, pero las publicaciones ya están eliminadas y no creo que puedan arreglarse.

Tendrás que esperar un tiempo hasta que el sistema levante la suspensión automáticamente.

Comment: eso quiere decir, que tengo que esperar un tiempo determinado para yo volver a dar respuesta.

Comment: Un tiempo *indeterminado*, si. Paciencia. Ten en cuenta que hasta que no tengas 50 de rep no puedes comentar en cualquier sitio, por falta de privilegios.   Lee también los motivos de cierre de preguntas, para evitar participar en preguntas que acabarán cerradas. Un saludo

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Pero lois6b, @JosueSantana puede editar la 3.ª respuesta, mejorarla y recuperarla, ¿no? Puedes ver tus respuestas eliminadas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/108654

Comment: @fedorqui, la cosa es que me reportaron como mala repuesta, si ellos saben que soy nob, no pueden estar haciendo daño a uno :(, no veo la intensión de ser eso

Comment: @JosueSantana ante todo, es importante siempre tener presente que aquí [se vota por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83). La persona más lúcida puede tener un mal día y lo que la comunidad pretende es crear una serie de preguntas y respuestas útiles para que ayuden a todos aquellos que las encuentren. Una mala respuesta es una mala respuesta independientemente de quien la escriba. Intenta ofrecer respuestas que realmente respondan, pon cuidado en lo que escribes y seguro que acumulas buenos puntos en poco tiempo. Fíjate en cómo hacen los otros para aprender.

Comment: @fedorqui Muchas gracias!!! por tu respuesta, y a clarar me bien sobre esta comunidad.