# ¿Existe la posibilidad de ocultar preguntas de un usuario en específico?

Tags: discusión, cuentas-de-usuario

Últimamente en el sitio principal he empezado a notar que existe cierto tipo de usuarios que como José Antonio comenta en [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2908/47499), en el sitio existen personas que llenan el sitio de preguntas en las cuales intentan que se les proporcione el código "ya hecho" de modo que ni siquiera se esfuerzan en aprender, al principio tratas de ayudar con sus preguntas, sin embargo cuando ves que entre una pregunta y otra no han gran cambio en el código, piensas que esas personas no deberían estar en este sitio.

Que no se malentienda lo que quiero decir, yo comprendo que nadie nace con el conocimiento de algo en especifico, y aplaudo a las personas que quieren aprender a programar de forma independiente. Sin embargo hay usuarios que por más que trates de hacer entender, simplemente no es posible.
Es por eso que pregunto la posibilidad de una función que permita ocultar automáticamente la preguntas de algún usuario en específico.
Espero no ofender a nadie con esta pregunta, y no me odien si es que eso significa algún tipo de conducta en contra de las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de añadir PHP y C# en la lista de etiquetas ignoradas :P

Comment: No, no existe esta opción. Pero probablemente puedes hacer algo mejor: votar negativamente y para cerrar estas preguntas, para que les sea cada vez más difícil formularlas.

Comment: No me queda para nada claro si estás preguntando si existe esa función o si estás proponiendo que se cree.

Comment: Hasta donde sé, esa función no existe. Lo más parecido que podrías conseguir sería crear un plugin para Chrome (o tu navegador preferido) que oculte las preguntas de los usuarios seleccionados.

Comment: @Mariano a lo que me refiero es que si no existe, ¿Creen que sería funcional?

Comment: @alexchvrches en ese caso, creo que deberías reetiquetarla, sacándole el [meta-tag:característica-nueva] y agegándole [meta-tag:discusión]. La etiqueta que usaste es directamente para solicitar que se agregue la funcionalidad, en cuyo caso creo que debería estar muchísimo más fundamentada. Si es de discusión, estarías invitando a que el resto de la comunidad lo hable... Además, le agregaría ese último comentario tuyo, para que quede más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente en la configuración del usuario existe la posibilidad de **ignorar** etiquetas la cual oculta al usuario las etiquetas que él determine pero no existe algo similar para usuarios.

<strike>Lo que podrías hacer como solución provisional es usar `-user:id_de_usuario` en la búsqueda.</strike>

No creo que debería implementarse una función ya que la premisa es [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)

Si las preguntas <strike>de un usuario</strike> te parecen de baja calidad, vota negativo y pasa a lo que sigue.

> IMPORTANTE: Se vota **con base en el contenido** no con base en quién hace la publicación

Eventualmente los  usuarios que reciban un proporción importante de votos negativos serán bloqueados automáticamente y no podrán publicar nuevas preguntas hasta que contribuyan positivamente al sitio. Véanse:

- [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)
- [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Sólo procura evitar caer en el [voto serial](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/663/65).