# ¿Se debería ir revisando las preguntas antiguas para no tener o para depurar preguntas de baja calidad?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Recientemente revisé una pregunta antigua a la que le di una respuesta, y me di cuenta que es demasiado amplia.

Recuerdo que en estas fechas al estar en fase Beta se era un poco más abiertos a estos tipos de preguntas por lo que formulé una respuesta.

Ahora la duda es: **¿se debería ir revisando las preguntas antiguas para no tener o para depurar preguntas de baja calidad?**

La pregunta en cuestión es esta:

[Enviar POST a PHP por medio de AJAX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax)

Comment: si son muy antiguas, no.. es un gasto de esfuerzo, dado la cantidad de preguntas malas que tenemos en este momento. y lo limitado que son los votos de cierre.

Comment: @gbianchi : Me parece muy pronto para hablar de preguntas "muy antiguas". Ni siquiera hemos cumplido un lustro :D

Answer (score 3):

## Respuesta corta

Yo te animaría a convocar un "clean-up" de las preguntas del "Beta Cerrado" ([created:..2015-12-14 is:question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A..2015-12-14+is%3Aquestion)) la cual es la época de las preguntas "más antiguas" de SOes.

## Explicación

Entiendo que pregunta pide orientación sobre la realización de lo que en otros sitios de la red se suele llamar "clean-up". Algunos sitios cuentan con una etiqueta en meta y en [wiki de dicha etiqueta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/clean-up/info) en META SO se describen los conceptos importantes.

Me parece que deberíamos agregar la etiqueta y su wiki acá no sólo por esta pregunta sino porque eventualmente será útil realizar "clean-ups" con objetivos específicos de forma similar a lo que se hace en esta pregunta al preguntar por tener como objetivo depurar el sitio de preguntas antiguas "malas".

Por otro lado, acá tenemos [Jornada de Limpieza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/65) en la cual me parece que no hay una propuesta específica de revisión de preguntas antiguas.

---

Anexo

Investigando encontré esta pregunta en SO Meta que no tiene respuesta aún.

- [What's the actual definition of what a Meta “cleanup request” entails, and what's the process for these requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361500/1595451)

Comment: Nótese que la pregunta sobre la que consulta es de mucho después de que se saliera del Beta privado. Es de septiembre de 2016, cuando la beta pública empezó a principios de diciembre de 2015.

Comment: @fedorqui Lo sé, pero considero que primero habría que empezar con el beta privado, luego el beta público, y así sucesivamente, en cualquier caso, esperemos a ver si Juan o alguien más se anima a "llamar a las armas" y ver que propone.

Comment: Ah, de acuerdo. Sí, podría ser útil, pues al fin y al cabo suelen ser preguntas con muchas visitas y poco ejemplarizantes :)