# Edición de preguntas/respuestas antiguas: ¿Algún consenso en cómo hacerlo?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

De vez en cuando, cuando no tengo nada mejor que hacer, se me dá por revisar respuesta y/o preguntas en las que participé y hacer un poco de limpieza, es decir, mejorar el título, quitar ruido, alguna que otra etiqueta, formateos varios,  en algunos casos voy borrando mi respuesta si considero que hay alguna mejor, etc. Siempre supuse que esto era algo inocuo y poco visible, sin embargo me acabo de dar cuenta (no me peguen) que estos cambios hacen aparecer a estas preguntas arriba de todo en la cola de las "activas".

¿Hasta qué punto estas ediciones pueden ser consideradas como loables mejoras y no como un vil truco para dar más visibilidad a preguntas y/o respuestas y eventualmente ganar algún que otro punto (me ha pasado)?

Comment: _Et tu Patricie?_ :P Ya en serio, la verdad es que no he visto ediciones de esas hechas por ti (aunque suelo moverme por la pestaña de Nuevas). Cuando encuentro una publicación "antigua" que ha sido editada de forma trivial, sí que he dejado algún mensaje mencionando este problema. Pero tampoco he dejado muchos que recuerde. Además, la línea es algo borrosa a veces entre una edición útil y otra trivial (intencionada o no).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, Hace un tiempo me sucedió algo así, edité una pregunta vieja que había respondido  y al poco rato recibí un +10, es cierto que es una linea muy difusa, de hecho, tampoco está mal haber recibido puntos por la misma, pero claramente abusar de las ediciones para conseguir visibilidad es es otro tema. Me quedó tranquilo y preocupado con que alguien este mirando estas cosas, por lo pronto me limitaré a cambios que sean significativamente positivos. Saludos.

Comment: Y digo yo: ¿ Cuál es el problema en conseguir algún *puntillo* extra ? Si es merecedora, pues bienvenido sea. Yo mismo no paso mucho por las `activas`, pero de vez en cuando lo hago. Y si alguna pregunta/respuesta llama mi atención y decido darlo un +1, es porque considero que lo merece; sea la pregunta de hoy o de hace un año :-)

Comment: Curiosidad lingüística: ¿es común en Argentina decir _se me da por revisar respuesta_? En España diríamos _me da por..._, sin el pronominal.

Comment: @fedorqui, el "me da por.." también se escucha, pero el "se me da por" es como más informal y común. Bah.. es una opinión...

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¡interesante! Nunca lo había oído así... Y perdona el _off topic_ :)

Comment: Relacionado [Jornada de limpieza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/65)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La intención es importante. Si editas para que tu pregunta/respuesta aparezca en las activas y así ganar puntillos estás abusando del sistema. Si editas porque piensas que esa pregunta/respuesta es subsceptible de una mejora significativa estás haciendo un uso en la buena dirección.

Pero como la telepatía todavía no está muy desarrollada habrá que evaluar esas ediciones según los [criterios del centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

> #### ¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?
>
> Siempre que veas que puedes mejorar una publicación y te apetezca.
> ¡Fomentamos la edición!
>
> Algunas razones comunes para editar son:
>
> - para corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía
> - para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla
> - para corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece
> - para añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados
>
> **No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales**: intenta
> mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo
> todos los problemas que encuentres.

Obsérvese que la antigüedad no es un criterio para decidir si editar o no.

Si ves 5 errores y editas hoy uno, la semana siguiente otro, la siguiente otro y así hasta 5 semanas conseguirás un mejor posicionamiento en las preguntas activas. Y quizás también una advertencia de un moderador.

Si editas los 5 errores de una vez mereces una felicitación.